# Canvas Arc Countdown, Multiple Arcs with Different Styles

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've created a "countdown" arc with canvas. So the background arc is a semi-circle, and the top arc "grows" based on the time left between two dates. (This particular example is from the 1st of July to the 31st).

Everything works as intended, but I can't figure out how to separate the arc styles.

I'm generally new to canvas, so any help would be appreciated. Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gDQhR/2/

The real code in question is:

```
        ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(255, 234, 93, .9)";
```

I only want to apply that shadow to the top arc. I'm sure there's a better way to organize the styling for each arc in general, and I think that'd be key to applying that style to just the single arc.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop applying the shadow effect by setting:

```
ctx.shadowBlur=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more global answer would be to talk about save() and restore() : with those two methods you can ... well... save all the current status of the canvas, then you modify it (strokeStyle, font, scale, ...), then after, by calling restore, you make the canvas brand new in the previously saved status.

Be warned that strokeStyle cannot use a gradient, so you have to draw a path that draws a ring/ring segment.

Rq 1 : a gradient is defined on a specific part of the context, it seems you were besides the drawing zone
 (around 75, 75)

Rq 2 : A good way of proceeding might be to build one intermediate function for each figure , it helps you understand/change the code.